# SignalR client CORS error when using Windows authentication

Tags: angular, authentication, cors, signalr

I am implementing Windows authentication on an ASP.NET Core 2.2 server application, and everything is working fine except SignalR in Angular 8 app. The error I am receiving is the following one:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:2110/api/aircrafts/hub/negotiate' from origin 'http://localhost:2302' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

*localhost:2302* is the client part running *Angular 8* with *@aspnet/signalr@1.1.4* and *localhost:2110* is the server part. Here is my server code:

**Startup.cs Configure Method**

```
app.UseCors("CORS");
app.UseAuthentication();
var relativeUri = webSettings.SignalRAircraftsUri.ToString();
app.UseSignalR(hubs => { hubs.MapHub<AircraftsHub>(relativeUri); });
```

**Startup.cs ConfigureServices method**

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CORS", builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .WithOrigins(webSettings.AllowedHosts.ToArray())
                    .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });

        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

*webSettings.AllowedHosts* contains *localhost:2302*.

**launchsettings.json:**

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:2110",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
```

And this is the Angular code:

```
const signalRConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(url).build();
signalRConnection.start();
```

where *url* is *localhost:2110/api/aircrafts/hub*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should not use the package `@aspnet/signalr@1.1.4` because it is abandoned and migrated by microsoft to the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr) `@microsoft/signalr` and it is already on version `3.1.0`, as you can see in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

About CORS, you should configure your CORS like:

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicy, builder => builder.WithOrigins(webSettings.AllowedHosts.ToArray())
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));
});
```